# How do I find what can decode ANSI_X3.4-1968?

Tags: python-3.x, ascii

If I am using

```
t = open(filename, 'r'):
print(t.encoding)
```

I am getting ANSI_X3.4-1968, but

```
t.readlines()
```

Will give me 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf2 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128). If I check the type

```
print(type(t))
```

I get class '_io.TextIOWrapper', which should still read the byte right? What logic am I missing here or do I need to parse something?
I tried

```
t = open(filename, 'r', 'utf-8'):
t.readlines()
```

And got 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf2 in position 10: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Try using open(filename, 'r', encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968')

Comment: From that I get 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Try this encoding ''ISO-8859-1'', it ranges from 0-255

Comment: ISO-8859-1 seems to crash my code base not sure why, but on another note, do you know if _io.TextIOWrapper can be read with read() or readlines()

Comment: `print(t.encoding)` isn't printing the file's "actual encoding". It's printing the system default encoding, which Python uses when you don't specify one explicitly. There is no expectation that opening an arbitrary file with this encoding will make any sense.